# Get the result of a function as a string for jQuery Datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Using [jQuery Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker), I'd like to change datepicker position based on window size (specifically: show datepicker at bottom on larger screens, show datepicker on top on smaller screens)

I'm trying to get the right position value with this snippet, but it doesn't work (Chrome tells me that `widgetPositioning() vertical variable must be a string`):

```
var position = $(window).resize(function(){
    return ($(window).width() <= 480) ? 'top' : 'auto';
}).resize();

$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    widgetPositioning: {
        vertical: position
    }
})
```

Where am I wrong? Here's a runnable code to play on

```js
var position = $(window).resize(function(){
    return ($(window).width() <= 480) ? 'top' : 'auto';
}).resize();

$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    widgetPositioning: {
        // vertical: position // doesn't work
        vertical: 'top'        
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it. It does not fix your code but modifies it. Give that a try?

```js
var position = "auto";

$(window).resize(function(){

console.log(position);

 var width = $(window).width();

    if(width <= 600) {
      position = "top";      
    } else {
      position = "auto";
    }
   
});

$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    widgetPositioning: {
        vertical: position // doesn't work  
        //vertical: 'top'        
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```